# Prevent conflict between lodash and underscore on front-end

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

There seems to be no bulletproof way to prevent conflict between underscore and lodash on the front-end.

We could do this:

```
<script src="/scripts/vendor/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script>
    window._us = window._;
    delete window._;
</script>
<script src="/scripts/vendor/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
```

but that doesn't seem to be good enough. Is there a way to use both libs or do we have to choose?

Comment: They have compatible APIs, why would you use both?

Comment: we are using some functions from underscore that don't exist on lodash eg _.where

Comment: Don't underscore and lodash both have a noConflict() method? (Call the method, don't try to do it manually.)

Comment: yeah, it didn't work for me and I am not really sure how it's supposed to work anyway, will investigate

Comment: If you need `_.where` or something else that lodash doesn't have, then why don't you just patch it in with [`_.mixin`](https://lodash.com/docs#mixin)? Trying to use both at the same time is, IMO, a mistake.

Comment: you might also review the [lodash changelogs](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog) to see about replacing functions like underscore's _.where with compatible lodash functions (eliminating the need for the underscore dependency)

Answer (score 15):

On the topic of `noConflict`, when underscore or lodash are loaded globally they will override the global `_` variable. Calling `noConflict()` will reverse this, setting `_` to its previous value and return the instance of `_`. In the example below I commented how the global `_` value will change after each action

```
<!-- the global _ will now be underscore -->
<script src="/scripts/vendor/underscore/underscore.js"></script>

<!-- the global _ will now be lodash -->
<script src="/scripts/vendor/lodash/lodash.js"></script>

<script>
// the global _ will now be underscore
window.lodash = _.noConflict();

// the global _ will now be undefined
window.underscore = _.noConflict();
</script>
```